# How do I import a 3D table in csv in python?

Tags: python, csv, matrix-multiplication

I have to import a 3-dimensional table of data in order to manipulate it in my Python script.

The 3 dimensions I have are:

1. Coverage
2. Age
3. Premium

The coverage rows and age column are not fixed, meaning there could me more or less than the sample below.

My current test data looks (FWD_FIXED_5YRS.csv) like this;

```
COVERAGE    Age 18  Age 20  Age 25  Age 30  Age 35  Age 40  Age 45  Age 50  Age 55  Age 60
50000.00    53.00   53.00   53.00   53.00   55.50   67.50   82.50   129.00  175.50  288.50
100000.00   54.00   54.00   54.00   60.00   74.00   117.00  146.00  198.00  331.00  536.00
150000.00   78.50   78.50   81.00   90.00   111.00  169.50  219.00  307.50  496.50  804.00
200000.00   108.00  108.00  108.00  120.00  148.00  222.00  292.00  410.00  662.00  1027.00
250000.00   87.50   87.50   90.00   102.50  124.00  165.00  235.00  350.00  557.50  1215.00
300000.00   105.00  105.00  108.00  123.00  147.00  198.00  282.00  420.00  669.00  1458.00
....
....
```

I've tried something from another qn but I seem to be only getting the first few columns:

```
import csv

with open('FWD_FIXED_5YRS.csv', 'r') as f:
    obj = csv.reader(f)
    X, Y, Z = [], [], []
    for i,row in enumerate(obj):
        if i>0:
             xstring = row[0]
             ystring = row[1]
             zstring= row[2]
             print (xstring, ystring, zstring)
```

Comment: do `cat FWD_FIXED_5YRS.csv | head ` or paste in a format that I can try the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done using the `pandas` module.
If you are OK to use `pandas` module, you could read your csv as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('FWD_FIXED_5YRS.csv', sep='\t', index_col='COVERAGE')
df
```

It would give the below result,

```
            Age 18  Age 20  Age 25  Age 30  Age 35  Age 40  Age 45  Age 50  Age 55  Age 60
COVERAGE                                        
50000.0     53.0    53.0    53.0    53.0    55.5    67.5    82.5    129.0   175.5   288.5
100000.0    54.0    54.0    54.0    60.0    74.0    117.0   146.0   198.0   331.0   536.0
150000.0    78.5    78.5    81.0    90.0    111.0   169.5   219.0   307.5   496.5   804.0
200000.0    108.0   108.0   108.0   120.0   148.0   222.0   292.0   410.0   662.0   1027.0
250000.0    87.5    87.5    90.0    102.5   124.0   165.0   235.0   350.0   557.5   1215.0
300000.0    105.0   105.0   108.0   123.0   147.0   198.0   282.0   420.0   669.0   1458.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing only first 3 elements in each row.

> ```
>          xstring = row[0]
>          ystring = row[1]
>          zstring= row[2]
> ```

If you are intending to print Coverage for each age, as you read the csv something like

> 50000.00 Age 18 53.00
>
> 50000.00 Age 20 53.00
>
> 50000.00 Age 25 53.00

To retain header (1st row) and the first column do as,

```
reader = csv.DictReader(fp)
for row in reader:
    coverage = row.pop('COVERAGE')
    for age, premium in row.items():
        print( coverage, age, premium)
```